# ffmpeg - how to make a preview with short bursts of scenes

Tags: ffmpeg

Given a list of timestamps, how can I make a movie where I will extract x seconds at each of the timestamps?

for example, if my list is [3, 8, 11], I would like to make a movie made of [3-4][8-9][11-12]

I know how to extract the frames at the timestamps, but not how to extract a chunk of the movie from a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='between(t,3,4)+between(t,8,9)+between(t,11,12)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -af aselect='between(t,3,4)+between(t,8,9)+between(t,11,12)',asetpts=N/SR/TB out.mp4
```

`-vf select (from video stream),setpts (for smooth timestamps)`

`-af aselect (from audio stream),asetpts (for smooth timestamps)`

Selection time ranges should be the same.